# Login to facebook account without exiting app using facebook client API

Tags: c#, facebook, windows-phone-8, winrt-xaml

I want to provide the user the option of posting to his facebook wall ,through my app. Inorder to achieve this , for facebook authentication and posting action I have used the facebook & facebook client API's provided by microsoft (their latest alpha version). I could also able to achieve the process of posting also using the API methods. The main problem , was on completion of Facebook authentication my app is getting relaunched newly , losing its existing instance. Is there any alternative ways so that I can achieve my scenario without exiting the app.

my authentication code here below

Session.ActiveSession.LoginWithBehavior("email,public_profile,user_friends,publish_actions", FacebookLoginBehavior.LoginBehaviorWebViewOnly);

Please let me know if some alternatives are possible.

Thanks,
Mawy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to install a combination of fast resume, and a UriMapper to correctly launch your app back to the right place after authentication. I dont' think Fast Resume is not required, however it provides a better experience as it should relaunch your app quicker.

Fast resume is define [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj735579(v=vs.105).aspx), UriMapping is outlined [here](http://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2013/11/14/sign-into-windows-phone-8-apps-with-facebook-login/).